# USB device not detected for Samsung Captivate - i897 after windows7 (64bit) is updated

Tags: android, usb, windows-7-x64, samsung-mobile

1. usb drivers not detected when windows7(64bit) is updated.
2. when phone is connected "unknown device" is displayed on status bar.

Followed the below process to clear this issue. please find in this link here http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/usb-device-not-detected-for-samsung-captivatei897/35a616d6-f0c4-4230-b5ac-e0db7d76fc52?page=1

Comment: still i haven't got solution for this issue...can anyone please suggest to clear this problem if u ve faced before.

Answer (score 1):

Install **Samsung Kies** in your system. That will install the required device drivers for Samsung.

If you have installed Kies already reinstall it.

Comment: i checked after installing Samsung kies and updated the same, but still my device not detected.
Had a live chat with samsung support, but my issue was not cleared